# Azure Logic Apps send JSON Message to ServiceBus

Tags: json, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I want to send JSON to Azure ServiceBus from a Logic App, but I'm struggling with the correct formatting (I think). The Logic App gets information from a SharePoint Online list item, so I can access it within the Logic App as dynamic content. For this post, assume the JSON template looks like this:

```
{ Title: '', CreatedBy:'' }
```

Now in the Logic App designer, I set the Content Type to "text/plain" to ensure the encoding is handled (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324290/logic-app-send-message-error-with-json)) and then added the template above to the "Content" field. It looks like this in Logic App designer (code view), which is what I expected:

```
"ContentData": "@{base64('{ Title: '', CreatedBy:'' }')}"
```

If I go back to designer and, between the single quotes for "Title", I add the field from my dynamic content, the designer (code view) looks like this:

```
"ContentData": "@{base64(concat('{ Title: '',triggerBody()?['Title'],'', CreatedBy:'' }'))}"
```

When I try to save, I get the following error:

> Failed to save logic app MyLogicApp. The template validation failed: 'The template action 'Send_message' at line '1' and column '163728' is not valid: "Unable to parse template language expression 'base64(concat('{ Title: '',triggerBody()?['Title'],'', CreatedBy:'' }'))': expected token 'RightParenthesis' and actual 'Identifier'.".'.

I feel like the error tells me the problem but I can't quite figure it out. Can someone help me with the correct formatting please?

From the article I linked to above, I also tried this but got the same error:

```
"ContentData": "@{base64(concat('{ Title: '', string(triggerBody()?['Title']),'', CreatedBy:'' }'))}"
```

Edit: I forgot to add that I found [this article](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/jmann/post/2016/04/23/Azure-Logic-Apps-The-template-language-function-json-parameter-is-not-valid) that recommended adding the decodeBase64 when working with JSON and Logic Apps. Not sure if it's relevant though as I'm not parsing from ServiceBus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find a solution with some trial and error. If was my dodgy formatting at fault so updating how I resolved in the hope someone else finds this useful.

The Logic App code view should look like this:

```
"ContentData": "@{base64('{ Title: {triggers().outputs.body.Title}, CreatedBy: {triggers().outputs.body.CreatedBy} }')}"
```

The Logic App designer view Content field should look like this:

```
{ Title: {triggers().outputs.body.Title}, CreatedBy: {triggers().outputs.body.CreatedBy} }
```

I'd love to post some citation or supporting articles but I've not been able to find any as yet - would appreciate if anyone has any useful resources on sending messages to Service Bus via Logic Apps to add them to this post. Thanks!